# How to add multiple pivots using DataTemplate in winrt UWP?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, winrt-xaml

I have a condition where I want to add multiple PivotItems(which is dynamic).
ie; I have a `List<CustomModel>` whose size is dynamic, And for every item in the List I want to create a PivotItem with header as CustomModel.Title.

Is it possible to achieve this with xaml alone by creating a DataTemplate and binding it to a Pivot?

Comment: Bind list to ItemSource of Pivot. Make it ObservableCollection instead of List

Comment: How will the pivot know which parameter to bind to? could you give me example of the xaml?

Comment: And what is custommodel? You won't be knowing it's properties?

Comment: Its a my own custom class which has a parameter called "title" which has to be bound to the pivotItems header.

Comment: It has got only one property? Then what you talking about other properties? From where does it come from?

Comment: No the custom class has many members

Comment: Then ffine. Write datatemplate for pivot item template,bind appropriate properties of custommodel. Finally bind ItemSource to ObservableCollection. When you add items dynamically since it's ObservableCollection pivot items will be added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is surely possible. See below sample solution

```
    <Pivot x:Name="TestPivot">
    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:TestClass">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderTitle, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:TestClass">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

Code behind for simulating the binding

```
    public sealed partial class BlankPage6 : Page
{
    ObservableCollection<TestClass> SampleSource = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();
    public BlankPage6()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        SampleSource.Add(new TestClass { HeaderTitle = "Test Header1", Content = "Test content 1" });
        SampleSource.Add(new TestClass { HeaderTitle = "Test Header2", Content = "Test content 2" });
        SampleSource.Add(new TestClass { HeaderTitle = "Test Header3", Content = "Test content 3" });

        TestPivot.ItemsSource = SampleSource;
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public string HeaderTitle { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Output:
[image]